# Begin animation when ContentControl.Content is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to fire an animation when a content control such as Button or ContentControl changes its content. My initial thoughts were to do this:

```
        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentElement">
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content">
                                    <ContentPresenter.Triggers>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="WHATGOESHERE">
                                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MyAnimation}" Storyboard.TargetName="Content"/>
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                    </ContentPresenter.Triggers>
                                </ContentPresenter>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>

            <Button Content="Hello"/>
        </ContentControl>
```

But I don't know which event fires when the ContentPresenter is changed/updated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no CLR-event for ContentChanged (much less a RoutedEvent required for EventTriggers) unfortunately.  However, given that you're dealing with a custom control, you can override the metadata for the Content property and provide your own callback within the control.

This may be about what you're looking for [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/5421e988-f729-4154-b1ab-e17e1b8b70d4/)

Obviously he's created a CLR-event to propagate content changes externally; you could also do the same just using a RoutedEvent instead.

Additional reading on OverrideMetadata [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597491.aspx)

Answer (score 19):

You can just write an attached property:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

static class ContentControlExtensions
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentChangedAnimationProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ContentChangedAnimation", typeof(Storyboard), typeof(ContentControlExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(default(Storyboard), ContentChangedAnimationPropertyChangedCallback));

    public static void SetContentChangedAnimation(DependencyObject element, Storyboard value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ContentChangedAnimationProperty, value);
    }

    public static Storyboard GetContentChangedAnimation(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (Storyboard)element.GetValue(ContentChangedAnimationProperty);
    }

    private static void ContentChangedAnimationPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var contentControl = dependencyObject as ContentControl;
        if (contentControl == null)
            throw new Exception("Can only be applied to a ContentControl");

        var propertyDescriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ContentControl.ContentProperty,
            typeof (ContentControl));

        propertyDescriptor.RemoveValueChanged(contentControl, ContentChangedHandler);
        propertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged(contentControl, ContentChangedHandler);
    }

    private static void ContentChangedHandler(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var animateObject = (FrameworkElement) sender;
        var storyboard = GetContentChangedAnimation(animateObject);
        storyboard.Begin(animateObject);
    }
}
```

and then in XAML:

```
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedViewItem}">
            <extensions:ContentControlExtensions.ContentChangedAnimation>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ThicknessAnimation To="0" From="30,0,-30,0" Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </extensions:ContentControlExtensions.ContentChangedAnimation>
        </ContentControl>
```

It's much easier and shorter than a new control.

Comment: If you change the `DependencyObject` callouts in the `Get..` and `Set...` methods to `ContentControl`, you don't need to do the type check in the callback method.

Comment: Excellent example, nice and simple....for the new WPF devs it might just be worth adding the xmlns:behavior="clr-namespace:<your app Namespace>" to the top of the XAML.....

Comment: This is not a behavior, it's an attached property.

Comment: Very nice & easy example, best answer here.

Comment: Works like a charm, perfect.