# WPF, `Loaded` event is only fired on first viewmodel initialization but not subsequent ones

Tags: wpf, view, render, viewmodel, eventtrigger

I initialize the view model of a UserControl multiple times like this

```
ChartControl = new SciChartControlViewModel(true, false, true);
```

The view is rendered via `ContentControl` like

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
     <ContentControl Content="{Binding ChartControl}"/>
</Grid>
```

I hook into the `Loaded` event within the view like this

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnViewLoadedCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>

</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

**Problem:** Only on the first initialization of the view model does the `Loaded` event fire. When I subsequently initialize the view model again the `Loaded` event is not fired anymore. Only when the control loses focus and is brought back into focus it fires.

**Desired Behavior:** How can I make sure that I capture in my view model each time when the view is entirely rendered? I need to capture this because some operations I perform in my view model on this control only work when the view is fully rendered.

Comment: Did you try the `DataContextChanged` event? Not sure if that works if you bound to the `Content` property. Otherwise you could overwrite the metadata for `Content` dependency property as descibed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831965/begin-animation-when-contentcontrol-content-is-changed)

Comment: @JanDotNet, awesome, this works. Though it still puzzles me why the Loaded event does not fire each time when the current view model instance is discarded and a new one instantiated. Perhaps because the view remains in place and hence does not load on subsequent view model instantiations but the data context changes? Please feel free to write up a quick answer, happy to mark it as desired answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that the view is initialized (and loaded) once and will be reused when changing the content.

You could try to use the `DataContextChanged` event - Not sure if that works if you bound to the `Content` property. Otherwise you could overwrite the metadata for Content dependency property as descibed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831965/begin-animation-when-contentcontrol-content-is-changed).

Comment: It works, I invoked the command from code behind (`var viewModel = (MyViewModel)DataContext;
if (viewModel.MyCommand.CanExecute(null))
    viewModel.MyCommand.Execute(null);`)